# What are we in for today?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

"Let go," said Annie.
Jack pulled on his pack and followed her.
*What are we in for today?* he wondered.

Does " *what are we in for today*" mean "how are we today"?
Why are there two prepositions *" in"* and *" for"* in this sentence?

Comment: You need to start using a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I will do it. have a great day or night!

Answer (score 1):

If you are 'in for' something (usually bad) it means that thing will happen to you soon.

I was caught stealing. I am **in for** a punishment when my father finds out. Our office has received 5000 orders. We are **in for** a busy day.

> be in for sth
> phrasal verb
> to be going to experience something unpleasant very soon

[Be in for something (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-for-sth)

Comment: My flag is marked as helpful.